# Listing system information in convenient format using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, date, operating-system, sysinfo

I hope someone can help me. I'm currently genertating a list of computer dates to see which need to be replaced (>3 years).

Is it possible to echo this in a csv or excel?

I made the following snippet:

```
 $env:COMPUTERNAME
 $ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
 $BIOS = Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_BIOS
 $BIOSageInYears = (New-TimeSpan -Start ($BIOS.ConvertToDateTime($BIOS.releasedate).ToShortDateString()) -End $(Get-Date)).Days / 365
 $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
 $OSInstallDate = ($OperatingSystem.ConvertToDateTime($OperatingSystem.InstallDate).ToShortDateString())
 $System.SerialNumber
 $ComputerSystem.Manufacturer
    $ComputerSystem.Model
    ($BIOS.ConvertToDateTime($BIOS.releasedate).ToShortDateString())
    $BIOSageInYears
    $OS=@(Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\System\Setup\Source* | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::$_}; Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion')
    $OS | Select-Object ProductName, ReleaseID, CurrentBuild, @{Name='InstallDate'; Expression={[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($_.InstallDate))}} | Sort-Object "InstallDate"
```

This gives me the following output:

```
PS U:\> U:\build.ps1
WS0***MH
Hewlett-Packard
HP Z440 Workstation
08-11-2017
3.81095890410959

ProductName                     ReleaseId CurrentBuild InstallDate        
-----------                     --------- ------------ -----------        
Windows 10 Pro for Workstations 1709      16299        19-04-2018 13:38:08
Windows 10 Pro for Workstations 1803      17134        03-05-2018 10:25:24
Windows 10 Pro for Workstations 1909      18363        05-07-2019 10:52:48
Windows 10 Pro for Workstations 2009      19043        14-06-2021 17:11:32
```

So i want the first installed date and date in years in my output. At the moment it only works for the bios date.

I just need this

```
WS0***MH
Hewlett-Packard
HP Z440 Workstation
19-04-2018 13:38:08 (first installed date - NOT Bios)
3.81095890410959 (age first installed - NOT Bios)
```

Comment: take a look at the `Get-ComputerInfo` cmdlet. it has a `-Property` parameter that can accept a list of props that you want ... or you can just ignore the ones you have no need for.

Comment: This would return most info, but not the installed date of the first install. So I'd have no clue how old the workstation is.

Comment: You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to add that column to your output.

Comment: @Lucas - as Bill_Stewart pointed out, you can always build onto what you already have with some variant of a calculated property. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first setup date of Windows 10 is hard to find in a reliable way. One way is to check the modify date of the Client Side Cache folder...

```
$ComputerSystem = Get-CimInstance  -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
 
$SystemInfo = New-Object PSCustomObject | Select ComputerName,Manufacturer,Model,FirstSetup,SetupAge
    $SystemInfo.ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $SystemInfo.Manufacturer = $ComputerSystem.Manufacturer
    $SystemInfo.Model = $ComputerSystem.Model
    $SystemInfo.FirstSetup = (get-item c:\windows\csc).LastWriteTime
    $SystemInfo.SetupAge = ((get-date) - $SystemInfo.FirstSetup).Days / 365

$SystemInfo | Export-Csv SystemInfo.csv
```

You might wan't to change the output format of `$SystemInfo.FirstSetup` to something other then system locale.